# First "if-then" statement won't redirect stdout to /dev/null on Mint

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement, stdout, linux-mint

so this is a really weird error. I've tested it on two installs of GNU/Linux, namely Arch Linux and Linux Mint 17.1. I've got a bash script I'm working on, and it starts with an if-statement.

```
if which apt-get &> /dev/null; then x="foo"
elif which yum &> /dev/null; then x="bar"
elif which pacman &> /dev/null; then x="baz"
```

It works fine on my Arch installation (with bash v4.3.33), but on my Mint installation (bash v4.3.11), it completes the if-statements without incident, but after the if-statements there's a prompt for user input and bash immediately prints from stdout (even though I'm fairly sure I redirected it to /dev/null). It looks like:

```
Choose an option: /usr/bin/apt-get
```

where "Choose an option: " is my prompt. This doesn't occur on Arch, and when I switched the order around to

```
if which pacman &> /dev/null; then x="foo"
elif which apt-get &> /dev/null; then x="bar"
```

the trailing output after my prompt stopped appearing.

Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Does `which` do the same thing on both of these systems?  It is sometimes aliased to a more complicated command.  Try `type which` on both systems.

Comment: Change `which` in the script to `type -P`, which is a bash builtin command.

Comment: The `type which` command shows `which is /usr/bin/which` on both systems.  I changed `which` to ``type -P`` and the output continued to do the same thing, but instead of it saying `/usr/bin/apt-get` it says `/path/to/script: 20: /path/to/script -P:: not found`

Answer (score 1):

Alright guys, I figured out what was going on; it was just a dumb mistake on my part, but I really appreciate the help from dg99 and glenn jackman.

I noticed that if executed in a graphical file manager (Nemo), and selected to "Run in terminal," that the weird output didn't happen. This prompted some testing via terminal and I discovered that the issue resolved itself if I executed the script by using `./script` instead of `sh script`. I don't really know why that's the case, but it resolved the issue pretty cleanly.

Comment: If it's genuinely a Bash script, `sh script` is wrong (whereas `bash script` is correct).

Comment: That makes sense, but for some reason I've always used `sh script`. I'll start using `bash` from now on (as it does have `#!/bin/bash` in the header). Thanks!